# Cannot locate RHN/DB.pm in @INC

Tags: centos, perl, spacewalk

I am trying to install spacewalk on CentOS 7 however i receive "Cannot locate RHN/DB.pm in @INC" error.

It says compilation was aborted in spacewalk-setup line 33 which is "use RHN::DB ();".

I tried installing RHN/DB with cpan however it gives me 404 error. What is RHN/DB ? It seems that it does not exist in google. What am I missing ? How do I install RHN/DB ?

Answer (score 1):

RHN::DB is provided by spacewalk-web package.

You probably missed this step https://github.com/spacewalkproject/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall#installing-spacewalk which should install all those spacewalk* packages and its dependencies.